# Por que esta Web AJAX no muestra resultado?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

**NOTA** no se explicar nada de este script pues fue algo que fui armando desde otra web **COPIE y PEGUE** dicho esto hice solo estos dos archivos NO se donde esta el error.

**EL PROBLEMA es que no se previsualiza la consulta ¿Por que?**

este es el archivo de conexion llamado:

> (db_connect_mysql.php)

```
    <?php
    $conexion = @mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "Admin456", "almacen");
    if (!$conexion)
    {
        printf("Error de conexion NO Utililzar 1.", mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    ?>
```

este es el otro archivo llamado

> (buscar.php)

```
<?php
//Archivo de conexión a la base de datos
include_once "db_connect_mysql.php";

//Variable de búsqueda
$consultaBusqueda = $_POST['valorBusqueda'];

//Filtro anti-XSS
$caracteres_malos = array("<", ">", "\"", "'", "/", "<", ">", "'", "/");
$caracteres_buenos = array("& lt;", "& gt;", "& quot;", "& #x27;", "& #x2F;", "& #060;", "& #062;", "& #039;", "& #047;");
$consultaBusqueda = str_replace($caracteres_malos, $caracteres_buenos, $consultaBusqueda);

//Variable vacía (para evitar los E_NOTICE)
$mensaje = "";


//Comprueba si $consultaBusqueda está seteado
if (isset($consultaBusqueda)) {

    //Selecciona todo de la tabla mmv001 
    //donde el nombre sea igual a $consultaBusqueda, 
    //o el apellido sea igual a $consultaBusqueda, 
    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "
    SELECT * FROM mmv001
    WHERE nombre like '%$consultaBusqueda%' 
    OR apellido LIKE '%$consultaBusqueda%'
    ");

    //Obtiene la cantidad de filas que hay en la consulta
    $filas = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);

    //Si no existe ninguna fila que sea igual a $consultaBusqueda, entonces mostramos el siguiente mensaje
    if ($filas === 0) {
        $mensaje = "<p>No hay ningún usuario con ese nombre y/o apellido</p>";
    } else {
        //Si existe alguna fila que sea igual a $consultaBusqueda, entonces mostramos el siguiente mensaje
        echo 'Resultados para <strong>'.$consultaBusqueda.'</strong>';

        //La variable $resultado contiene el array que se genera en la consulta, así que obtenemos los datos y los mostramos en un bucle
        while($resultados = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
            $nombre = $resultados['nombre'];
            $apellido = $resultados['apellido'];
            $edad = $resultados['edad'];

            //Output
            $mensaje .= '
            <p>
            <strong>Nombre:</strong> ' . $nombre . '<br>
            <strong>Apellido:</strong> ' . $apellido . '<br>
            <strong>Edad:</strong> ' . $edad . '<br>
            </p>';

        };//Fin while $resultados

    }; //Fin else $filas

};//Fin isset $consultaBusqueda

//Devolvemos el mensaje que tomará jQuery
echo $mensaje;
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test-autollenado</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#resultadoBusqueda").html('<p>JQUERY VACIO</p>');
});

function buscar() {
    var textoBusqueda = $("input#busqueda").val();

     if (textoBusqueda != "") {
        $.post("buscar.php", {valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda}, function(mensaje) {
            $("#resultadoBusqueda").html(mensaje);
         }); 
     } else { 
        $("#resultadoBusqueda").html('<p>JQUERY VACIO</p>');
        };
};
</script>




</head>

<body>
<center>
<form accept-charset="utf-8" method="POST">
<table>
<tr><td>lol</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="busqueda" id="busqueda" value="" placeholder="" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off" onKeyUp="buscar();" />
</td>
<table>

<!--<input type="submit" name="submit" value="busqueda" />-->
</table>
</form>

</center>
<div id="resultadoBusqueda"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Esta es la consulta que utilize para la base Datos:

```
CREATE TABLE `mmv001` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `apellido` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `edad` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of mmv001
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `mmv001` VALUES ('1', 'Juan', 'Villa', '33');
```

Esta fue la guia tutorial que encontre y desde aqui fue que la hice:

https://mimentevuela.wordpress.com/2015/08/09/busqueda-instantanea-con-ajax-php-y-mysql/

***NO MUESTRA NADA  al escribir en el cuadro de texto y tampoco arroja ningun error***

Comment: ¿Qué muestra la consola del navegador? Necesitas dar más detalles.

Comment: Bro no muestra previsualizacion al escribir en el cuadro de texto

Comment: descargaste y agregaste el js de Jquery bien?

Comment: men como es eso ojala yo supiera hacer eso?

Comment: @JuanCarlosVillamizarAlvarez Pon esto en el head de tu página `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` Y no hagas copia y pega de otras páginas sin saber lo que haces, así no se aprende a programar.....